# Submitting a form the web page only refreshes

Tags: javascript, html, webkit

I'm trying to submit this form :

```
form id="fform" method="post" action="?index.php" autocomplete="on"
```

with this:

```
webView.evaluateJavaScript("document.getElementById('fform').submit();")
```

The problem is that the App does not go forward but refreshes the page.
What can I do?

Answer (score 1):

Here is the mistake `?index.php`. This should be `/index.php`

```
form id="fform" method="post" action="/index.php" autocomplete="on"
```

> *If you already in `index.php` page please change the action url*

Try this

```
document.getElementById("fform").submit();
```

**Or**
Use [JQuery](https://jquery.com/)

```
$('#fform').submit();
```

**To change action attribute:** You can do it easily by using *JQuery* `attr()` function.

```
$('#fform').attr("action", "/your/url/here");
```

Comment: The fact is that I copied the HTML form line as it was in the webpage I'm scraping. Can you explain exactly in what  I have to change the action URL?

Answer (score 0):

Your URL in the action attribute must be of the same page. I think you should change it to some other and then try.